# Ploting a list of points with different color that is determined by another list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm sure this is quite simple but couldn't find any examples.
I have a list of tuples (x,y) and I wish to print these in color according to another list of labels using matplotlib.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual imports

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

faking some data

```
labels = 'a b c a b c a b c'.split()
tuples = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (5, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

you need a way to map labels to colors, and a dictionary is a mapping, isn't it?

```
color = dict(zip(set(labels), 'red,blue,purple,green'.split(',')))
```

next, you can plot the individual points with their color, with just a
difference from usual stuff, you specify a `zorder` greater than the default
value of `1` (the reason will be explained later).

```
for (x, y), label in zip(tuples, labels):
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=color[label], zorder=2)
```

Now, if you want to have a legend, you may be tempted to add a `label=label`
to the previous statement, followed by a `plt.legend()`, but that won't work,
because you will have a line in the legend for each of the data points.

You need to plot a single point for each of the different labels, with the
correct color, the correct label and the correct size, and then call
`plt.legend` (that now will do the right thing), but, at the same time, the
*auxiliary* dots must be invisible.

This *invisibility* can be obtained plotting the extra points **behind** the
last point, whose coordinates `x` and `y` are still known to the interpreter,
using a `zorder` value less than what we used for the regular data points.

```
for label in set(labels):
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=color[label], label=label, zorder=1)
plt.legend()
```

[image]